# Is it possible to NOT show the Debug Side Bar when debugging in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As an attempt to simplify the look and feel of VS Code for new users (who do not consider themselves as developers), I'd like to hide the Debug Side Bar forever:

[image: the debug side bar]

What's currently happening is, every time I hit F5, the Debug Side Bar pops open even after I hide it with `cmd+B`. Is there some way I can force it to stay hidden?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your settings look for

> Debug: Open Debug
>
> ```
>     Controls when the debug view should open.
> ```

and choose the `neverOpen` option.

Or put   `"debug.openDebug": "neverOpen",` into your settings.json.